# Importing .FBX files

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to add animated/rigged 3D objects using Helix toolkit but I can't import fbx files. Is there a way to import fbx files into WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio Mesh Pipeline to convert FBX to CMO, and import the CMO. Since FBX format is a very powerful but complicate format, converting to CMO may not get correct bone result, but you can try at least. And bone skinning only supports in HelixToolkit.SharpDX version.

Comment: Does HeelixToolkit now support import of CMO? I could not find it in the list of supported import formats?

Comment: It supports CMO in SharpDX version. Please refer to BoneSkinning Demo.

Answer (score 0):

Helix toolkit does not have support for fbx files as far as i know. Have a look at the **Import** section of the toolkits [feature list](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/wiki/Features-(WPF)).
I think the only way is to convert from fbx to one of the supported formats and import this.

Answer (score 0):

New HelixToolkit release contains Assimp importer, which will support FBX import.